# URL routing not working in php codeigniter 3.1.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing, codeigniter-3

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
**$route['mangeAds/(:any)'] = "Admin_navigation/mangeAds";**
```

in the above code **mangeAds**  is not working.
$route['mangeAds/(:any)'] = "Admin_navigation/mangeAds

any mistake on this.

Comment: Syntax look fine ! i would like to know the case (upper/lower case) of Controller "Admin_navigation"  in your Controller

Comment: @kashif this is my class, this class name is i have put to file name too. class Admin_navigation extends CI_Controller {

Comment: 1) $route['mangeAds/(:any)'] = 'Admin_navigation/mangeAds' (i would also use ' instead of ''  )  , 2) Since syntax look fine , i would like to know that Admin_navigation controller is working stand alone . i mean is it working using absolute path url  .

Comment: yes it is working file when we call directly the function by the ctrl class name.

Comment: So when you use the url,for instance,localhost/admin_navigation/mangeads you don't get any errors...  but when you use the url localhost/manageads you get an error which says what?